# Select Distinct in Node jS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a problem where I want to be able to get all data related to the classroom with no duplicate. My code look like this. The problem is that in console data are displayed correctly with no duplicate. But in sites no data display.

This is data display in Console

```
[ '6 Usaha', '6 bakti' ]
```

**Timetable Schema**

```
var TimetableSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    timeslot: {
        required: true, 
        'type': Number,

    },

    classroom :{
        type:String, 
        required: true, 
    },

    subject :{
        type:String, 
        required: true, 
    },

    teacher :{
        type:String, 
        required: true, 
    },

    year :{
        type:String, 
        //required: true, 
    },

    session :{
        type:Number,
        //required:true,
    }


})

var Timetable = mongoose.model('Timetable', TimetableSchema);
module.exports = Timetable;
```

**Route**

```
router.get('/timetable',mid, function(req,res){
  Timetable.distinct("classroom",function(err,timetable){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(timetable);
    res.render('admin_content/timetable',{'timetable':timetable});
  });
});
```

**Views**

```
<tbody>
   <% timetable.forEach(function (timetable) { %>
   <tr>
   <td><%= timetable.classroom %></td>
   <td><a class="button" href="/subject/edit/<%= timetable.classroom %>"</a>View&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <% }) %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: did you try to render some text in each loop? example: <td>This should be a classroom</td>

Comment: I add  <td>This should be a classroom</td> to the loop and its working fine. But not with the "<td><%= timetable.classroom %></td>" which suppose to view classroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like below ,As your array doesn't contains js objects its just `primitive` values `[ '6 Usaha', '6 bakti' ]`

```
<tbody>
   <% timetable.forEach(function (value) { %>
   <tr>
   <td><%= value %></td>
   <td><a class="button" href="/subject/edit/<%= value %>"</a>View&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <% }) %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.code working, Just a quickfire question what do you means by array doesn't contains js objects its just primitive values [ '6 Usaha', '6 bakti' ]?

Comment: I mean your code would have valid if your array was like `[{classroom:6. },{classroom:7}]`,but it just contains primitives (`Strings`) datattype